# Example data sets in Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset

There are several example data sets in Matlab, for example *wind* and *mri*. If you execute the command `load wind` you will load the data in the data set *wind*. Some are included in toolboxes and some appear to be included in standard Matlab. These example data sets are valuable as test data when developing algorithms.

Where can one find a list of all such data sets included in Matlab?

Comment: I wonder if http://ml.sheffield.ac.uk/~neil/datasets/ could be helpful for you?

Comment: Note that any list outside matlab would have to take into account version numbers and toolboxes to be complete. A command inside matlab would be nice but I think `demo` is probably as good as its going to get.

Comment: wind data can be found here http://bioinformatics.intec.ugent.be/MotifSuite/INCLUSive_for_users/CPU_64/Matlab_Compiler_Runtime/v79/toolbox/matlab/demos/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enter `demo` in matlab to get a list. The wind table is part of `Example — Stream Line Plots of Vector Data`, etc.

For the tables on your computer, have a look at:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\toolbox\matlab\demos
```

Answer (score 2):

The example data is located in `.mat` files in `../toolbox/matlab/demos`. 
The following data is available in `MATLAB 2014a`:

```
% in matlab run:
> H=what('demos')
> display(H.mat)
```

You can also use your favorite Linux console:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/matlab/demos$ ls *.mat -1 | sed -e "s/.mat//g"
```

This is my list for readers who can not try it on their machine while reading this answer:

```
accidents
airfoil
cape
census
clown
detail
dmbanner
durer
earth
flujet
gatlin
gatlin2
integersignal
logo
mandrill
membrane
mri
patients
penny
quake
seamount
spine
stocks
tetmesh
topo
topography
trimesh2d
trimesh3d
truss
usapolygon
usborder
vibesdat
west0479
wind
xpmndrll
```

While the command  `demo` in MATLAB 2018b will start a help browser with some demos:
[image: help on demo in matlab 2018b]

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of **all available dataset** and their description in the following link :

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/sample-data-sets.html